# How to have Java Iterable return base subtype from extended generic

Tags: java, generics, iteration

I am attempting to make a class that sub-classes Iterable.  This is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512250/how-can-i-make-my-class-iterable-so-i-can-use-foreach-syntax). However, I need to have the objects in the list be sub-classes of a specific class, e.g. QObject in my example below. In addition, I need my iterator to implement specific methods related to the ListIterator interface.

The problem is that my inner class that implements the ListIterator interface does not "return" the base generic type QObject in my implementation.  There is something wrong with how I am doing the QueueListIterator generics.

Now, if I declare the Queue in my example code with Queue <QObject> it works.  This must be providing the information needed to allow the iterator to get the type correct.  However, just declaring it as Queue does not, even though the base generic type is QObject AND my other methods in the Queue class use the base generic type.

So, my question is why does this happen and is there a way to specify QueueListIterator to discern the base generic type?

```
    public class Queue<T extends QObject> implements Iterable<T> {
        /**
         * The list of items in the queue.
         */
        protected List<T> myList;

        // other methods and defs

        public final Iterator<T> iterator() {
            return (new QueueListIterator());
        }

        public final ListIterator<T> listIterator() {
            return (new QueueListIterator());
        }

        private class QueueListIterator implements ListIterator<T> {

            protected ListIterator<T> myIterator;

            protected QueueListIterator() {
                myIterator = myList.listIterator();
            }

            @Override
            public void add(T o) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("The method add() is not supported for Queue iteration");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return myIterator.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasPrevious() {
                return myIterator.hasPrevious();
            }

            @Override
            public T next() {
                return myIterator.next();
            }

            @Override
            public int nextIndex() {
                return myIterator.nextIndex();
            }

            @Override
            public T previous() {
                return myIterator.previous();
            }

            @Override
            public int previousIndex() {
                return myIterator.previousIndex();
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("The method remove() is not supported for Queue iteration");
            }

            @Override
            public void set(T o) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("The method set() is not supported for Queue iteration");
            }
        }
    }

    // testing code
    public static void test(){

            Queue q = new Queue();
            // put some stuff in the Queue
            QObject r1 = new QObject(q.getTime(), "A");
            q.enqueue(r1);
            QObject r2 = new QObject(q.getTime(), "B");
            q.enqueue(r2);

            // Does not work! 
            // incompatible object types, Object cannot be converted to QObject in the for( : ) construct
            for (QObject qo : q) {
                System.out.println(qo);
            }
    }
```

Comment: I edited the question to have that because my first post missed the LT and GT signs.  Yes, Queue<QObject> q does provide the necessary type information. But, I believe that I should not have to provide the base generic type when declaring the Queue if I am okay with getting QObjects

Comment: This is just a problem in your usage of generics.  It should be `Queue<QObject> q = new Queue<QObject>()`.

Comment: I understand the Queue<QObject> works.  However, if I just declare the queue as Queue q = new Queue(), then my other methods (not shown) such as T removeFirst() WILL get the generic base type QObject without it being provided from the declaration, because they know that the type T must be a subtype of QObject.  However, I cannot get the Iteratable to do this same thing.

Comment: Yes.  There is no way at all to make that work.  But you shouldn't worry about it, because you should never be using `Queue` without a type parameter anyway.

Comment: Louis, I agree now. I have to study the generic type system even more now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the raw type `Queue` is the same as using the erasure of `Queue`. The reason that `T removeFirst()` allows you to retrieve a `QObject` but `Iterator.next()` does not is that `T removeFirst()` and `Iterator<T> iterator()` erase differently. The erasure of a type variable is the erasure of its left-most bound, so `T` erases to `QObject`, but the erasure of a parameterized type is that type without any type arguments, so `Iterator<T>` erases to `Iterator`. ([source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6))

There is no way to get that working with the raw type, and you should use `Queue<QObject>` instead. In some cases you may also be able to use `Queue<?>` as a reference type. (See [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2891664).)

Also see [*What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2770692/2891664)

Comment: This is helpful, albeit disappointing.  It seemed reasonable that there should be away for my inner class to be made aware of the base generic type in the manner that I wanted. However, understanding that raw types should not be used indicates my base misunderstanding of the type system. It is a little clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

What if you declare q this way:
Queue < QObject > q

Comment: It is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I consider this a comment, not an answer. My original post already pointed out that this will work.