# Java using getters and setters for array

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture

I would like to get this inventory_ array from another class.

```
public class File { 
Object[][] inventory=new Object[50][2];
//Reading file to the inventory array.
}

public class Stack { 
//I want to copy inventory array to here 
}
```

Lets assume I have 2 different classes and I have 2 different arrays.

```
public class inventory { 
Object[][] inventory_=new Object[50][2];
} 

public class bag { 
Object[][] bag_=new Object[50][2];
}
```

So I want to compare inventory_'s items with bag_'s item in the bag class. How can I implement this.

Comment: Arrays are immutable references and have a final length property; exactly how do you intend to "change" and what do you want to "observe"? There isn't enough here to tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: please explain the use case scenario.

Comment: can you check out the design pattern. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern .  what you are looking for is in the same lines.

Comment: Basically I want to copy this inventory array to another array from another class.

Comment: "Lets assume" *what*?

Comment: Sorry EJoshuaS I edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tehcnically it is possible to have a getter, that just returns the reference to the private `Object[][] inventory` array.

But this approach considered unsafe, because in this case, external code may change the internal state of your `File`class via modifying the `inventory` array state.

For example:

```
class File {

    Object[][] inventory=new Object[50][2];


    public Object[][] getInventory() {
        return inventory;
    }

}
```

For this case, let's consider this example code:

```
class Stack {

    private File file;

    public Stack(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    void processSomething() {

        Object[][] stackInventory = file.getInventory();

    }
}
```

And in case you assign something to `stackInventory[1][1]` (for example), then `inventory[1][1]` array element into `File` class instance also will change its value.

And thus it is not considered a good design approach, because it may lead to hard-to-catch bugs in your project.

There are two solutions for this case.

The first one: make defensive copy of the array in your getter.

```
public Object[][] getInventory() {
    Object[][] newInventory = new Object[50][2];

    // copy inventory array contents to the newInventory array

    return newInventory; // and returning safe copy of the array
}
```

In this case as you have Object, it is still possible to change internal state of the objects if they are [mutable ones](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-mutable-and-immutable-objects/).

Either make your objects immutable, or [employ deep copy approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564832/how-do-i-do-a-deep-copy-of-a-2d-array-in-java) upon making defensive copy of the array.

And another way to resolve this issue, which I recommend, is using the [**Iterator**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterators-in-java/) approach.

In your `File` class [make a method that returns the Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849154/can-we-write-our-own-iterator-in-java) over your `inventory` array. And use this iterator in the external code to iterate over the `inventory` elements.

Or you may make your `File` class [**iterable**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512250/how-can-i-make-my-class-iterable-so-i-can-use-foreach-syntax) and use `foreach` operator to process the `inventory` elements.

Once again, upon designing your approach, keep in mind the [mutable/immutable class](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-mutable-and-immutable-objects/) types. And if it is possible, keep your classes immutable.

Also it is not recommended to name your classes likewise the standard java sdk classes. Your `File` class could be confused with `java.io.File` class by someone who will read your code later.

The same goes for your `Stack` class, which can be confused with `java.util.Stack` class. Please use other, more descriptive and unique names.